# Why my docker-compose container is not running?

Tags: docker, docker-compose, debian

I have a Virtualbox VM running debian 10.11 whith docker, everything is up to date.
I want to start a very basic container from a debian image using deocker-compose.

I have the following docker-compose.yml file

```
version: "3"
services:
  deb1:
    image: debian:latest
```

I run the command `sudo docker-compose up -d` but the container is not running when running `sudo docker ps -a` so I try to start manually `sudo docker start <container_id>` but the container is still not running and I have a success return code (`echo $?`).

It works well when I use docker command to create the container `sudo docker run -td --name deb1 --hostname deb1 debian:latest`

Does someone have any idea to fix that ?

thanks
Louis

Comment: A bare `debian` image doesn't have any application built into it.  Do you have a custom Dockerfile or something more interesting to run?  (What do you expect the main container process to be?)

Comment: I don't have any other Dockerfile or configuration script. I just want to deploy containers to do some ping to learn and test docker, in particular networking.
Do you mean that a container can be run only if a service is running inside ?

Comment: UPDATE: I really think I need to run a process into this container, in my case I tried with sleep as entrypoint in my docker-compose.yml

Comment: You should think of a container as a wrapper around a single _process_; conceptually, think of it a little more like your browser than a terminal window, in terms of what you would typically do with it.  (So, for example, can you "get a shell inside" your browser; or does it make sense for your browser to "keep it running" after it's exited?)  Running an unmodified `debian` container is not unlike booting a rescue CD to a RAM disk: you can play with it if you want, but you'll lose everything you've done once it's exited.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

UPDATE: a container can only work if a service is running inside. As David Maze said, the Debian image can be extended in a Dockerfile for example.

Answer (score 2):

You can add `command: tail -f /dev/null` to you compose file to keep container running:

```
version: "3"
services:
  deb1:
    image: debian:latest
    command: tail -f /dev/null
```